# Rails/PaperTrail: approving edits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, paper-trail-gem

In the app I am working on we are using PaperTrail to not only keep up with changes made by the original user but also by changes that have been made to a User with a role of "Contributor" who has access to make changes to authorized profiles.

The one piece I can't put together is not allowing unapproved paper_trail versions to not show up as "live". We will be building in a dashboard area where the Profile Owner will approve edits. Just needing some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use **two different classes**: one to hold the *live, approved* User, the other one to hold the *contributed, unapproved* User. Let's call them `User` and `PendingUser`.

You can have `PendingUser` inherit everything from `User` and just overwrite the `table_name`. Or, event better, both can have a common class they inherit from - e.g. `BaseUser` (or a common *concern*). You'll also need a reference to the original `User` (`PendingUser#user_id`), in order to know, who the changes belong to. So you'll need to write migrations for the `pending_users` table and something like this:

```
class BaseUser
  # Everything that used to be within your User class
end

class User < BaseUser
  self.table_name = 'users'
  has_one :pending_user # Or has_many, see the last paragraph
end

class PendingUser <  BaseUser
  self.table_name = 'pending_users'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now there are two ways of setting up **PaperTrail**, which will lead to two different approaches:

1. The **default way** - PaperTrail stores everything by using the `Version` model. This means both `User` and `PendingUser` will be serialized in here, so no need to change anything
2. **Specialized classes & tables**: PaperTrail versions Users as `UserVersion`, which means you'll need to provide a `PendingUserVersion` class & table (pretty simple, just inherit everything from `UserVersion`, appart from the `table_name`).

So far so good. If your contributors are allowed to see pending users created by other contributors, then you're pretty much done - you'll just want to write the logic for the **approving mechanism**: basically you copy the attributes of the live version of a `PendingUser` to the live version of a `User` (except for `PendingUser#user_id` of course). After approving changes, you might want to remove the `PendingUser` and the `PendingUser` versions, or pick up all these versions and change their class to `User` (**merging** unapproved versions with the approved ones).

If your contributors are **not** allowed to see each others **pending** contributions, then you'll be having a **User has-many PendingUsers** relationship. It might get a bit more complicated, because you'll need to think about how, after approving a User, all other PendingUsers made by other contributors will referr to an outdated User version.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Added the User reference to PendingUser.